# Conditional expected value of a maximum of uniform random variables

Tags: conditional-expectation, conditional-probability, expected-value

I have $X_{1}$,$X_{2}$... $X_{n+1}$ independent uniform random variables on [0,1]. Let $Z=\max(X_{1},X_{2}... X_{n})$.

Let $c$ be a constant s.t $c \in [0,1]$

What is the following conditional expectation?

$E(Z|X_{n+1}<Z<c)$

I am aware that I should ideally find $F(Z|X_{n+1}<Z<c)$ in order to find the pdf and then the expectation but am quite stuck, I haven't been able to find solutions elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $c > 0$. We have $f_X(x) = [0 < x < 1], \, f_Z(x) = n x^{n - 1} [0 < x < 1]$,
$$\operatorname{E}(Z \mid X < Z < c) =
\frac {\operatorname{E}(Z \, [X < Z < c])}
 {\operatorname{P}(X < Z < c)} = \\
\frac {\iint_{x < z < c} z f_X(x) f_Z(z) \, dx dz}
 {\iint_{x < z < c} f_X(x) f_Z(z) \, dx dz} =
\frac {\int_0^{\min(c, 1)} z^{n + 1} dz}
 {\int_0^{\min(c, 1)} z^n dz}.$$

Comment: This was very helpful thank you! The next thing I tried to do was apply this methodology with a different $Z$. if I define $f_Z(x)=n(n-1)(1-x)x^{n-2}$ I end up with $\frac{\int^{min(c,1)}n(n-1)(1-z)z^ndz}{{\int^{min(c,1)}n(n-1)(1-z)z^{n-1}dz}}$ which doesnt seem to make sense to me. Can you see what I have done wrong?

Comment: I assume your $f_Z$ is supported on $[0, 1]$ and the integrals are from $0$ to $\min(c, 1)$. Then what you have is correct, why do you think that it's wrong?

Comment: The assumptions are correct. It appears I made an error when calculating the limits to check convergence! Sorry about that additional follow up.

Comment: I have posted a follow up question here:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3379219/conditional-expected-value-of-a-maximum-of-uniform-random-variables-with-differi?noredirect=1&lq=1