# Probability with uniform random variables

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, expected-value

Let $X_{1}$,$X_{2}$... $X_{n+1}$ be independent uniform random variables on [0,1].

let Z be the 2nd highest value in $\{X_{1},X_{2}... X_{n}\}$

let $c$ be a constant s.t $c \in [0,1]$

let $b$ be a constant s.t $b \in [0,1]$ and $b<c$

What is the $prob(X_{n+1}<Z<c,b<Z)$?

My attempt using the method from [Conditional expected value of a maximum of uniform random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3311353/conditional-expected-value-of-a-maximum-of-uniform-random-variables).

$$prob(X_{n+1}<Z<c,b<Z)={\int_{b}^{c} n(n-1)(1-z) z^{n - 1} dz}.$$

Is this correct? If not where am I going wrong?

Comment: Is $Z$ the "second highest value" (= second to the highest when sorted) in $X_1,\cdots X_n$ as you wrote it or $X_1,\cdots X_{n+1}$ ?

Comment: up until $X_n$ as I wrote, the crucial part is that $X_{n+1}$ is independent from Z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right:

$Z$ follows a Beta$(n-1,2)$ distribution as the second largest random variable in a sample of $n$ independent uniform random variables - check [order statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Order_statistics) for this. The density of $Z$ is then:

$$f(z)= n(n-1) z^{n-2} (1-z) 1_{(0,1)}(z) $$

(This is intuitively clear : $z^{n-2}$ is the probability that $n-2$ independent uniform are below $z$, and $1-z$ that a further independent uniform random variable is above; once you have chosen one of the $n$ indices to be the one that achieves the second record, you have $n-1$ others to choose to be the one of the first record)

Since the event $X_{n+1}$ is independent of $\{X_1, \ldots, X_n\}$, the two r.v. in the pair $(X_{n+1},Z)$ are independent, with density the product of their respective maginals. Set $D=\{(x,z) \in [0,1]^2: x<z, b<z<c \}$ and compute :

\begin{align}
P(X_{n+1}<Z ,b<Z<c)
& = P((X_{n+1},Z) \in D ) \\
& =\int x f(z) 1_{(x,z) \in D} dx dz \\
&= \int_{b}^{c} z f(z) dz  \\
& =  n(n-1) \int_{b}^c z^{n-1} (1-z) 1_{(0,1)}(z)
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Every arrangement is equally likely to occur
So z is second highest so n-2 things are less are and 1 is greater . This has probability k.z^(n-2)*(1-z)
To calculate k we will put integration from 0 to 1 = 1

Giving K=n.(n-1),  Kn+1 < z have probability z again. Yeah I think u r absolutely correct.

Comment: Sequence of symbols " 0 to 1 = 1 K=n.(n-1), Kn+1 < z" deserves maybe words between some of them, don't you think ?... The first quality of an answer should be to be understable, beyond bringing something...

Comment: My mistake really sorry